# How do you prove a function g has a max and min and that f of g does not have a max on R?

Tags: general-topology, derivatives, elementary-set-theory, weierstrass-approximation

Question: Let g: $\mathbb{R}$ $\to$$\mathbb{R}$ be a function (not necessarily continuous) which has a maximum and minimum on $\mathbb{R}$.Let $f:$ $\mathbb{R}$ be a function which is continuous on the range of g. Does $f$ of $g$  necessarily have a maximum on $\mathbb{R}$? Prove your answer, or provide a counterexample.

How exactly do I solve this? I have no conception on what to do? My guess was that I could use $sin(x)$ or some other trig function?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.

We can build $g$ as follows: set the maximum and minimum to be $\pm 1$, by setting $g(1) = 1, g(-1) = -1$. Set everything in between $-1$ and $1$ to be anything that's not $0$, like say $\frac 12$.

Now for the rest of the function, make $g(x)$ always be positive for $x>1$, but tend to $0$, and similarly, make $g(x)$ always be negative for $x<-1$, but tend to $0$.

Now we choose $f: [-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ which is continuous and attains a unique maximum at $x=0$ (there are many such examples; you could simply take a triangular spike, or take $\cos(x)$, for example). Clearly, $f(x)$ will get arbitrarily close to its maximum at $0$, since $g$ tends to $0$ at either end, but $f(x)$ will never actually attain this maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f=1/x$ and let $g$ be some appropriate function whose range contains $(0,1)$, for example $g(x)=x$ on $(0,1)$ and $-1$ for negative values and $1$ for values greater or equal than $1$. Then $f\circ g$ is unbounded.

Comment: Is $f(x)=\frac1x$ continuous on $\mathbb R$?

Comment: It is continuous on its domain, which is $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, namely all numbers except zero. Although some textbooks might call zero an asymptotic discontinuity or infinite jump or something like that. Anyhow $1/x$ is also continuous on the range of the $g$ I described, this range being $\{-1\}\cup (0,1]$, which is I think what you asked for. If you need the $f$ to be defined is all of $\mathbb{R}$ you can extend $1/x$ to zero by setting, say, $f(x)=0$, and it would still be continuous on the range of $g$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following two $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ functions, identical except at a single point:

- $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$,  which is continuous, taking values in $(0,1]$
- $g(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ for $x\not=-1$ and $g(-1)=-\frac12$, taking values in $\{-\frac12\}\cup (0,1]$ and having a maximum of $f(0)=1$ and a minimum of $f(-1)=-\frac12$

Then $f(g(x))=\frac{(1+x^2)^2}{1+(1+x^2)^2}$, which does not have a maximum, but does have a supremum of $1$ which is approached as $x \to \pm \infty$ and looks like

[image]

This is a variant of hdighfan's suggestions