# Maximum of a composite function of a continuous and non-continuous function

Tags: solution-verification, continuity

g(x) is a function which has a maximum and a minimum on , not (necessarily) continuous.
f(x) is a continuous function. Does  ∘  necessarily have
a maximum on ?

I need either to find a counterexample, or to produce a proof.

I have difficulties with finding a discontinuous function, which has a maximum and a minimum on R, since I have to use a composite function later.

UPD: My (not very well-thought) suggestion would be f(x)=x^2, which is continuous, and g(x)=(x^3-1)/(x^2-1), which is discontinuous (at x=1, x=-1) but has both minimum and maximum (at (0,1) and (-2,-3) respectively).

∘  = ((x^3-1)/(x^2-1))^2, which has two minima, but no maxima.

Comment: $\frac{x^3-1}{x^2-1}$ does not really have _minima_ or _maxima_, but rather _critical points_. A minimum is (per definition) a point $x$ such that $g(y)\geq g(x)$ for all $y\in\mathbb{R}$. Maybe have a look at $\frac{x}{1+x^2}$

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3708108/how-do-you-prove-a-function-g-has-a-max-and-min-and-that-f-of-g-does-not-have-a

Comment: x/(1+x^2) is continuous.

Comment: Again, it brings me to the realization that, if we want a discontinuous function to have a minimum and a maximum, the only suitable type of discontinuity is removable (or, maybe, jump).